# What are the symptoms of trial version expiration of ajax uploader control?

Tags: trialware, ajax-upload

What are the symptoms of trial version expiration of ajax uploader control control? I have problems with postbacks ...

http://ajaxuploader.com/default.htm

Comment: Wouldn't this question really be better directed at the author/publisher of the control?

Comment: Yeah, that's true but this control is quite popular so I believe other will also benefit from the answer.

Comment: Interesting how .NET people seem to be willing to pay for something that is available for free in pretty much every other environment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"It will stop working."

This is the official explanation. Well nothing specific, unfortunately ...

It finally stopped working. When you use the control in just throw an exception, so it is clear when the trial period expires.